# getting alphabets after applying sentence tokenizer of nltk instead of sentences in Python 3.5.1

Tags: python, mysql, tokenize, punctuation

```
import codecs, os
import re
import string
import mysql
import mysql.connector
y_ = ""

'''Searching and reading text files from a folder.'''
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Users/ultaman/Documents/PAN dataset/Pan     Plagiarism dataset 2010/pan-plagiarism-corpus-2010/source-documents/test1"):
for file in files:
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        x_ = codecs.open(os.path.join(root,file),"r", "utf-8-sig")
        for lines in x_.readlines():
            y_ = y_ + lines
'''Tokenizing the senteces of the text file.'''
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
raw_docs = sent_tokenize(y_)

tokenized_docs = [sent_tokenize(y_) for sent in raw_docs]

'''Removing punctuation marks.'''

regex = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation)) 

tokenized_docs_no_punctuation = ''

for review in tokenized_docs:

new_review = ''
for token in review: 
    new_token = regex.sub(u'', token)
    if not new_token == u'':
        new_review+= new_token

tokenized_docs_no_punctuation += (new_review)
print(tokenized_docs_no_punctuation)

'''Connecting and inserting tokenized documents without punctuation in database field.'''
def connect():
    for i in range(len(tokenized_docs_no_punctuation)):
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'root', password = '', unix_socket = "/tmp/mysql.sock", database = 'test' )
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO splitted_sentences(sentence_id, splitted_sentences) VALUES(%s, %s)""",(cursor.lastrowid,(tokenized_docs_no_punctuation[i])))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect()


After writing the above code, The result is like

            2 | S      | N                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
|           3 | S      | o                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
```

|               4 | S      |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
|               5 | S      | d                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
|               6 | S      | o                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
|               7 | S      | u                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
|               8 | S      | b                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
|               9 | S      | t                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
|              10 | S      |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
|              11 | S      | m                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
|              12 | S      | y                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
|              13 | S      |
|              14 | S      | d
    in the database.

```
It should be like:
     1 | S      | No doubt, my dear friend.
     2 | S      | no doubt.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nw = []
for review in tokenized_docs[0]:
    new_review = ''
    for token in review: 
        new_token = regex.sub(u'', token)
        if not new_token == u'':
        new_review += new_token
nw.append(new_review)
'''Inserting into database'''
def connect():
    for j in nw:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'root', password = '', unix_socket = "/tmp/mysql.sock", database = 'Thesis' )
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO splitted_sentences(sentence_id,  splitted_sentences) VALUES(%s, %s)""",(cursor.lastrowid,j))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making the following edits(use what you would like). But this is what I used to get your code running. Your issue is that `review` in `for review in tokenized_docs:` is already a string. So, this makes `token` in `for token in review:` characters. Therefore to fix this I tried -

```
tokenized_docs = ['"No doubt, my dear friend, no doubt; but in the meanwhile suppose we talk of this annuity.', 'Shall we say one thousand francs a year."', '"What!"', 'asked Bonelle, looking at him very fixedly.', '"My dear friend, I mistook; I meant two thousand francs per annum," hurriedly rejoined Ramin.', 'Monsieur Bonelle closed his eyes, and appeared to fall into a gentle slumber.', 'The mercer coughed;\nthe sick man never moved.', '"Monsieur Bonelle."']

'''Removing punctuation marks.'''

regex = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation)) 

tokenized_docs_no_punctuation = []
for review in tokenized_docs:
    new_token = regex.sub(u'', review)
    if not new_token == u'':
        tokenized_docs_no_punctuation.append(new_token)

print(tokenized_docs_no_punctuation)
```

and got this -

```
['No doubt my dear friend no doubt but in the meanwhile suppose we talk of this annuity', 'Shall we say one thousand francs a year', 'What', 'asked Bonelle looking at him very fixedly', 'My dear friend I mistook I meant two thousand francs per annum hurriedly rejoined Ramin', 'Monsieur Bonelle closed his eyes and appeared to fall into a gentle slumber', 'The mercer coughed\nthe sick man never moved', 'Monsieur Bonelle']
```

The final format of the output is up to you. I prefer using lists. But you could concatenate this into a string as well.

Comment: Output of tokenized_docs is:  [['"No doubt, my dear friend, no doubt; but in the meanwhile suppose we talk of this annuity.', 'Shall we say one thousand francs a year."', '"What!"', 'asked Bonelle, looking at him very fixedly.', '"My dear friend, I mistook; I meant two thousand francs per annum," hurriedly rejoined Ramin.', 'Monsieur Bonelle closed his eyes, and appeared to fall into a gentle slumber.', 'The mercer coughed;\nthe sick man never moved.', '"Monsieur Bonelle."', 'No reply.',....

Comment: Thanks. But how can we pass objects of list into database then?

Comment: Assuming splitted_sentences is of type string this line is accurate -  `cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO splitted_sentences(sentence_id, splitted_sentences) VALUES(%s, %s)""",(cursor.lastrowid,(tokenized_docs_no_punctuation[i])))`    . Otherwise, concatenate into a string using `" ".join(tokenized_docs_no_punctuation)`  .